# Relevance percentage between two string

Tags: c#, search, comparison, metrics

How to get relevance percentage between two string in C#?

Comment: Do you mean "relevance"?

Comment: my bad.. yes i mean relevance

Comment: How are you defining "relevance"? Are we talking character-based relevance (length comparison, number of characters in common, common character ordering, etc.) or something more abstract like relevance of meaning (relating "character" and "letter" as being *relevant*, even though lexicographically they're different)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for something similar to the the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), which is the distance between two strings is given by the minimum number of operations needed to transform one string into the other?

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple answer for this, but have a look at Wikipedia's [string metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) article. There are lots of different approaches, though the most widely known is probably the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), which assigns an integer ranking to a pair of strings to quantify the 'distance' between them.

Answer (score 0):

check out the open source package SimMetrics on sourceforge - this should cover every possible need fairly simply.